# Problems using HttpUrlconnection to do login and upload an image

Tags: java, android, file, post, httpurlconnection

I've made an API which has an authorization part and a body part. The body part is for users to upload an image. For the basic auth part, it just need the username and the password. For the uploading part, it needs two parameters and an jpeg image file. I just got from some resources for uploading file but not combining the login part, so I modify it myself, but I don't know what's wrong in my code, it doesn't work. The following is my code:

```
 public String multipartRequest(String urlTo, Map<String, String> parmas, String filepath, String filefield, String fileMimeType) throws CustomException {

        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;

        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);


            URL url = new URL(urlTo);


            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            ///// certification
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            SSLSocketFactory newFactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(newFactory);
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            String a = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] data = a.getBytes();
            String info = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", info);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileMimeType + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            // Upload POST Data
            Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = parmas.get(key);

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(value);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }


            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            fileInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomException("error e");
        }


    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to use httpurlconnection to do both login and uploading files? In my code, I add both the following lines, is this a problem? I mean use "Content-Type" for multiple times(Login and Uploading files):

For Login part:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

For uploading file part:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

But I call them at the same time(same function), is this a problem?

Comment: okay you wanna upload file and text via one request right ?

Comment: I want to do authorization first and then for body parameters, I need to pass three values which are "text", "text", and "image file". These are for one API url.